# Styling Option_Select in Ruby Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, forms

Having a really tough time styling Rails Option_Select for forms, I've tried adding a class as well as just finding the element's direct ID and styling it but nothing has worked.

Option_select class:

```
<%= f.select :activity, options_for_select([['Cookery 1', 'ckry1']], { :class => 'opt-form-select' }) %>
```

CSS

```
.opt-form-select {
   font-size 4rem;
}
```

Nothing worked for the above so I used the old dev tools to select the element directly and edit css:

```
select#post_activity {
    font-size: 4rem;
}
```

Neither fix has worked, I've even tried adding styles directly to the option_select form but that didn't work either:

```
<%= f.select :activity, options_for_select([['Cookery 1', 'ckry1']], { :style => 'font-size: 4rem; background-color: blue' }) %>
```

Any ideas on how I can work around this?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can't. This element is rendered by the OS, not HTML. It cannot be styled via CSS. There are replacement plug-ins that look like a SELECT, but are actually composed from regular HTML elements that CAN be styled.

Comment: What plugins can I checkout?  Thanks for your help

Comment: I recommand you not using a plugin but just  style the element the way you want, you can check this: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp